# Setting up a default value for the field in Azure B2C user profile

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to set a default value of one custom field in User Profile. This field should not be visible to the user during sign up process using deafult signup signin policy.

I want to set it in baxkgroud or setimg it as a deafult value of that field.

Now the question is, is it possible to set a value of field without showing it on to the page using buildin SignUpIn policy in Azure B2C tenant?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to set a default value of one custom field in User
>   Profile. This field should not be visible to the user during sign up
>   process using deafult signup signin policy.

If you want to make the field not be visible to the user during sign up process, you could try to make entry (a claim) to your signup user journey. And to do this, you need to configure the entry as a dropdown, and define if it is required.

For the details, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom).